# Rich text and parameterized queries, should I be worried?

Tags: php, mysql, input, validation

For this particular project I will be using **PHP 5.3** & **MySQL with parameterized queries** and **CKE Editor**.

A little background on what my situation is:

The users on the site don't interact with each other.

All the users have private conversations with me only (confidential information), which contain richtext.

I've limited the CKE editor to limit the user to basic html, bold, images and miscellaneous formatting.

Now, two things:

1.)Do I still need some form of validation? If a user tries to input html or php or any other code in the rich text form, could it have any possible effect on my site? Or will it just be outputted as simple text once it's echo'd from the database?

2.)Is there anything else I should be worried about?

I haven't started on the project yet so I'm asking this to be prepared when I get to the user input part.

What do you recommend I do in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.)Do I still need some form of validation? If a user tries to input
>   html or php or any other code in the
>   rich text form, could it have any
>   possible effect on my site? Or will it
>   just be outputted as simple text once
>   it's echo'd from the database?

Definitely you should, there are a number of ways to bypass those ways using unicde, hex and more formats.

> 2.)Is there anything else I should be worried about?

You should be worried about [Cross-Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS). You need to use [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function at the minimum.

```
echo htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

**Possible Solution:**

You can use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/):

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   **malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS**) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

**Useful Resources:**

- [PHP Security Guide](http://php.robm.me.uk/)

Comment: First: You say I should, but I don't know how to do that. Suggestions?
Second: You say to use htmlentities as minimum, are you saying there's more to it than that I could do? If so, then what?

Comment: I saw that right after I clicked "Add Comment". Thanks! Now, will that address both of the problems? Or am I naive to think that's all I need to worry about?

Comment: @Tek: HTML Purifier will take care pretty much, hopefully. Check out their docs to know more about it :)

Comment: I like how you added "hopefully" lol. Don't trust programs written by other people? I guess that's why a lot of programmers try to "reinvent" the wheel often. Either way, this was more than I could have asked for and I'm sure this will meet and exceed my expectations. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tek: Welcome and glad to see that you understood the programmers' nightmare there :)